# Calculating $\lim\limits_{j \to \infty} \frac{j^{j/2}}{j!}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, exponentiation, limits-without-lhopital

\begin{align*}
 & \lim\limits_{j \to \infty}{j^{\,j/2} \over j!} \\
\end{align*}

This problem is from a real analysis textbook in the chapter on the natural log and properties of exponents. I'm struggling with how to approach this. I don't think you would use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Take logarithms.

Comment: Ratio test plus the fact that $(1+1/n)^n\to e$ should do it for you (the ratio of successive terms goes to zero).

Comment: Do you know about Stirling's approximation?

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: Krantz Real Analysis 4th edition. ISBN 978-1498777681. Page 225.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the limit. Then, it is :

$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{n/2}}{n!} \Leftrightarrow \ln L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\ln n^{n/2}-\ln n! \right)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\ln L =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{2}\ln n - \ln n!\right)$$

Now we will use the fact

$$\ln n! = n \ln n - n + \mathcal{O}\left(\ln n\right)$$

which is called [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (actually it is a consquence of the original formula, more information can be found in the link and credits to **Jack D'Aurizio** for mentioning it as well).

$$\begin{align*}\ln L &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{2}\ln n - n \ln n + n - \mathcal{O}\left(\ln n\right)\right)\\&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n-\frac{n}{2}\ln n\; -\mathcal{O}\left(\ln n\right)\right) \end{align*}$$

But $\mathcal{O}\left(\ln n\right) \to 0$ and you should be able to finish now.

Comment: Such approximation is just a consequence of the rectangle or trapezoid rule, the actual Stirling's approximation is $$ n! = \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$ incorporating the obscure constant $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio True point ! Thanks a lot for adding it as well.

Answer (score 4):

The ratio test is a more elementary tool:
$$\frac{(j+1)^\tfrac{j+1}2}{(j+1)!}\,\frac{j!}{j^{\tfrac j2}}=\frac{(j+1)^{\tfrac{j}2}\sqrt{j+1}}{(j+1)j^{\tfrac j2}}=\underbrace{\sqrt{\Bigl(1+\frac1j\Bigr)^j}}_{\begin{array}{c}\downarrow\\\sqrt{\mathrm e}\end{array}}\,\frac1{\sqrt{j+1}}\to 0$$

Comment: The ratio test shows that that the corresponding infinite series will in fact converge, and since it converges the terms must approach zero. This is the simplest answer. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a really clever trick, but is it perhaps more of an established technique?  I could imagine trying this with other expressions in which a factorial appears, but it's not something that I've come across before.

Comment: @TobyBartels: It's just a variation on standard methods.

Comment: @Bernard :  Maybe to you.  To me, the idea of proving that a sequence converges to zero because its sum as a series converges is a clever twist.  Usually it's easier to find the limit of a sequences than even to decide whether a series converges.  (I mean the kind that people write down with nice formulas; of course, they're equivalent in theory.)

Comment: One could also state it directly as its own rule:  If the sequence of ratios of successive terms of a sequence converges to a limit with absolute value less than 1 (or more generally has both liminf and limsup with absolute value less than 1), then the original sequence converges to 0.  It's easy to prove this without bringing in series; one would call it the Ratio Test for Sequences.  And now i can Google that and find hits; so that's the answer to my question.  Still a test that hadn't occurred to me before, so I'm glad to learn it now.

Answer (score 2):

Without invoking Stirling's approximation, the Hermite-Hadamard inequality, the $\log$-convexity of $\Gamma$ or the trapezoid rule (all viable approaches), one may simply notice that by defining
$$ a_n = \frac{n^n}{n!^2} $$
we have 
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1}{n+1}\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}_{\text{bounded}} \to 0 $$
as $n\to +\infty$, hence your limit is zero as well.